# what is the syntax of the stash attachment image?

Tags: bitbucket-server

our company uses the git stash, every time we need attach an image of the sonar report just like this

```
[![f1.PNG](attachment:622/ff240462b5%2Ff1.PNG)](attachment:622/ff240462b5%2Ff1.PNG)
```

then the page will show the image I capture.

could you tell me what's the syntax and theory of this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markdown syntax guide is [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html#Markdownsyntaxguide-Images)

In short, the format is [!Alt text](image url). So for your example:

- Alt text is "f1.PNG"
- Image URL
  (a local attachment) is "attachment:622/ff240462b5%2Ff1.PNG"